# how to replace the text value of Google Autocomplete text box

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using Google Places autocomplete text box in my application which works well.
Following is sample code from google.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Now in the Text box if I type 'Avenidas'
It shows values like 'Avenidas, Bryant Street, Palo Alto, CA, United States'
which is also good. but when I select this value.
The marker on map shows address
Avenidas, 450 Bryant Street Palo Alto, CA, United States

Now My requirement is that when user selects the value it should show the value 
Avenidas, 450 Bryant Street Palo Alto, CA, United States in the text box.

I tried

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {}
```

and tried to set the value using following line of code.

```
input.value = place.name+', '+address;
```

But it doesn't really show the set value on the page. but changed value shows on console log.
What am i missing ?

following is page code. Added an extra text box on which value sets fine.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding-left: 14px;  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
        width: 401px;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
}

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
    zoom: 13
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  //autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    document.getElementById("displayAddress").value=place.name+', '+address;
    document.getElementById("pac-input").value=place.name+', '+address;

    //console.log(input.text);
  });


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="displayAddress" type="text">
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need more code snippets to help

Comment: Yes, provide a jsfiddle. It's difficult to see what happens here.